# How to send ruby script stdout, as it processes, line by line, to an iframe in rails 3.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Is it possible to display the output of a ruby script as it processes, line by line, in an iframe in rails? I am using rails 3.1. If so, how?

STDOUT is updated by the ruby script after each query, and it looks something like this:

```
Runtime: Sun Feb  5 20:43:35 PST 2012
Querying MYSQL resource table......   0 sec
Querying xxxxxvtlnta06 for 29841 : xxxxx... ...  22 sec
Querying xxxxx1vtlnta06 for 34599 : xxxx...   0 sec
Querying xxxxx1vtlnta06 for 37565 : xxxx.. ...   1 sec
....
```

For what it's worth, here is the central part of the `*.rb` script, which is actually just a wrapper for a legacy perl script.

```
va_all  = 'legacy.pl var1 var2 var3' 
  puts #{va_all}
  puts "\n"
  readme = IO.popen("#{va_all}")
  while readme.gets do
     puts $_
  end
  readme.close
```

Now if I could just get this in a web browser...
Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it's possible to attach to stdout, but what's the problem of writing the output into a real log-file and then display this output in your iframe? that's basically what i am doing for sinastrano https://github.com/phoet/sinastrano

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've looked at the Sinastrano, and it is excellent.  The use of the js object literal in the is interesting.  Still, I am looking for a way of pushing to the browser, rather than polling.  And before I can get get back to it, I need to figure out why 'therubyracer' is not recognized by execjs.  I will update this thread with my ultimate solution (or notice of a career change ;-).